# Linux Command to list all FTP users in shell including the users created using vsftpd

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, ftp, vsftpd

I have created a few ftp accounts/users on my CentOS server using vsftpd. Now I would like know the username of that accounts using SHELL. I have root password to access the SSH.

I have tried to find in the /etc/password using command

> nano /etc/passwd

but there is no any list of created FTP users found.

Comment: Check `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and look for variable `userlist_file` ( if you've enabled it with `userlist_enable=YES` ). This should point you to where the list is stored.

Comment: @MarekRost i have not enabled anything similar to "userlist_enable=YES". So can you please tell me the steps to enable this ?

Comment: Vsftpd has more methods to manage users - Explicit list of names, emails, users from system accounts... I cannot predict it. You need to open the configuration file `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to know which method is used. Generally people resolve to either use custom list of users (if variable `userlist_enable` is `YES`) or system accounts (if variable `USE_LOCAL` is `YES`). In first case, there will be additional file with users. In second case you won't be able to tell exactly - best would be to open `/etc/passwd`, look for users with `id>=1000` and remember if you created them.